# Detect if string has decimal

Tags: c#, string

I'm printing in my header a string that have number values, some of them have decimals and some of them do not. What I want to do is to print the value with the decimal if it exists and add a preceding "$"; otherwise, just print the value but taking the decimal part ".00"

This is my code:

```
var listDay = data.Where(c => c.Fecha >= actualDate && c.Fecha <= actualDateMax).ToList();
var haveDataDay = listDay.Count() > 0;

    <h4 class="semi-bold">
        @if (haveDataDay)
        { @valueDateDay.ToString("F2") }
        else
        { @this.FP("lbl.loader.nodata") }
    </h4>
```

Some of the values I have are:

```
2112.34
99.00
20.00
456.12
```

and the output I'm looking for is:

```
$2,112.34
99
20
$456.12
```

Comment: Try using regex, http://regexr.com/3eh0c , see the replace section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect if a decimal is an integer by finding if there is a remainder after dividing by 1:

```
99 % 1 == 0 // true
456.12 % 1 == 0 // false
```

So, your final code might look like:

```
valueDateDay.ToString(valueDateDay % 1 == 0 ? "N0" : "C2");
```

---

**Update**: Given this may not work nicely for floating point numbers or other cultures, as pointed out in the comments, it may be safer to use `% 1 < epsilon` where `epsilon` is some small number (since this appears to be currency, something that represents an immaterial amount, like `0.0000005`, which should take care of the floating point issues):

```
valueDateDay.ToString(valueDateDay % 1 < 0.0000005 ? "N0" : "C2");
```

If your application is internationalized but you want to use an explicit currency format, that would also be easy enough to replace as well, maybe something like:

```
string.Format(valueDateDay % 1 < 0.0000005 ? "{0:N0}" : "${0:#,0.00}", valueDateDay);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string FormatNumber(string s)
{
    decimal d;
    if (!decimal.TryParse(s, out d)) return null;
    if (d % 1 == 0) 
    {
        return d.ToString("F0");  //Will format as fixed with zero decimals
    }
    else
    {
        return d.ToString("C2");  //Will format with currency symbol and two decimals
    }
}
```